# ul with background image and left floated li items

Tags: html, css, background, html-lists

I have a `ul` list with background image

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: url("../images/columns_sep_thumbs.png") repeat-y 50% 0;
}
```

With the following style for `li`

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

the image disappears when li items float left, any suggestions?

```
<ul>
        <li>
            content1
        </li>
        <li>
            content2
        </li>
        <li>
            content3
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Try adding `li:after { content:''; display:block; clear:both; }`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/lutenuwu/2/edit

Comment: how your expected result should look like finally?

Comment: this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062134/why-do-my-image-background-disappear-on-float-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) pseudo element to the `ul`

```
ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;        
    display: table;
}
```